# How to Configure PageSpeed in AppEngine - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pagespeed

Recently, I started my Development using `AppEngine` as my Application Server. Then, `PageSpeed Service` caught my attention and I failed to get this to work.

[Along my studies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Custom_PageSpeed_configuration), I found out that PageSpeed is also configurable under `appengine-web.xml`. So, I guessed that doing this should enable the service. The fact - It doesn't, due to this:

> You must have billing enabled to use the PageSpeed service. To enable
>   billing, go to the Administration>Application Settings section of the
>   Admin Console, click the Enable PageSpeed Service checkbox, and click
>   Save Settings.

I had enabled the billing, but not `PageSpeed Service`. According to [PageSpeed Doc](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service):

> PageSpeed Service is in a limited field trial, and is not currently
>   accepting new signups. If you are interested in this technology,
>   consider using our open source server modules.

Based on the quote above, does it mean that AppEngine *no longer supports* `PageSpeed Service`? Any ways to get this to work?

Comment: I believe that as a service it's just still in pre-beta -- no "no longer supports" about it -- but you should be able meanwhile to DIY with the open-source software per https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module -- have you tried that?

Comment: @AlexMartelli Hi Alex, sorry for my late response. Hopefully that google open up this service ASAP, and yeah, I am aware about the "open source service modules", but I prefer not to go for this path now.